# Errors when calculating box dimension of Mandelbrot set?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, fractals

I'm trying to calculate the box dimension of the Mandelbrot set's boundary, but i'm getting the wrong numbers. I'm using [the wikipedia definition of dimbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension), which is `Dimbox(S) = Lim ε->0 of log(N(ε))/log(1/ε)`, where ε = box side length and N(ε) = number of boxes required  to cover it.

When I get to box length = 0.01 (as in, every pixel on the border of the mandelbrot is one box) the box count is 17,964, which ends up giving a dimbox of 2.13, which should be correct.

---

However, as far as I understand it, you can't really calculate the dimbox by just having a really small value for ε, and it should instead be more of a trend that can be seen with a linear regression when plotting `log(N(ε))` on the y-axis and `log(1/ε)` on the x-axis for many values of ε. When I do this, I have the points

(log(1/2),log(45))

(log(1/1),log(122))

(log(1/0.5),log(315))

(log(1/0.01),log(17964))

which when plotted give this result [(Plot of points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icnn6.png).

However, this slope ends up being approximately 1.2, whereas by definition the box dimension should be at least 2, as Dimh <= Dimbox, and Dimh of mandelbrot = 2.

---

Would it be accurate to just have the smallest value of ε for the proof, or would it be required to have all values leading up to it and doing the linreg?

Did I do any mistakes in my calculations that are giving me this inaccuracy?

[Here's an imgur album of the different box dimension images I've created for this calculation  if it's necessary.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDA8w.jpg)